# Why won't one of my gas stove's burners ignite?

Tags: repair, appliances

I have zero experience working on stoves. We have a 3-year-old Whirpool and the right-front burner won't ignite properly.

When I turn the dial *for that* burner it sparks one or two times and then stops - the burner doesn't light.

If I turn that burner's dial so gas starts and then turn one of the *other* three burner's dials, the front-right burner lights. [I learned that this works because whenever one igniter sparks, they all spark]

I've watched several videos but I can't determine if I need to replace the spark electrode or the igniter wiring harness. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might revise to share the model number.

Comment: `I can get it to ignite if I turn one of the other dials` ....  this is confusing .... please edit the sentence to make it clearer

Comment: @jsotola I made an edit to hopefully clarify that statement.

Answer (score 1):

How many clicks, sparks, does it usually take to ignite? If you have gas on, and try to ignite another burner, it will ignite. You have sparks when you try to ignite this one by itself? If so, then the igniter is good, unless it normally sparks longer, then it could be faulty. However, you probably have a faulty gas valve. It is not opening the gas for ignition.

What is the stove model number? Can you post a video of the problem?